# URL.createObjectURL() is slow

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, real-time, web-worker

I created the library [uwork](https://github.com/franciscop/uwork), however launching each of the processes takes some time so it is not suitable for real time applications. Doing some performance benchmarks I got to [this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/0hwhzjbr/1/) to illustrate the problem:

```es6
let external = (new Date()).getTime();
let blob = new Blob([`
  let internal = new Date();
  console.log("Creation:", internal - ${external} + 'ms');
`], {"type": "text\/plain"});
let file = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let ww = new Worker(file);
```

It takes any time between 50-400ms to create the file and the web worker. Is there any way to optimize this? Why does it take so long?

This is totally okay for "long" processing times since then the launching time is negligible, but it's not okay for real time applications such as video analysis which is where I want to apply it with at least 10fps (100ms/run).

---

EDIT

After [some testing](https://jsfiddle.net/0hwhzjbr/2/) this takes 50-400ms as well, so I strongly think that it's `URL.createObjectURL()` (or `new Blob()`) the one that takes this time and not the creation of the web worker on itself:

```
let external = (new Date()).getTime();
let blob = new Blob([external], {"type": "text\/plain"});
let file = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
fetch(file).then(res => res.text()).then(file => {
  console.log("Fetched:", new Date() - parseInt(file), 'ms');
});
```

Comment: Creating a new worker involves creating a new thread, which (depending on host OS) a significant operation.

Comment: I tried a jsperf to just do `createObjectURL()` and while it doesn't seem *extremely* fast it doesn't seem critically slow.

Comment: Oh the function on itself is instantaneous, it's the *execution of the file that it creates* what is slow. That's why my examples are made that way, to show that the execution time of the string js (*inside*) and the script calling it (*outside*) are different. Note the backticks around some code.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia did you find a solution to this?

Comment: The example 1 doesn't even work anymore due to some security restriction issue so ‍♂️
However my second example now seems to take 5-10ms, so that might have improved? This is a fairly old question and never found a solution back in the day, please feel free to comment/answer with any updates